# Posting feed on other user's wall using FB.api

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, feed

My requirement : Post message automatically to user's activity log without showing any dialogue.

I am using FB.api for this. You can view the code that I used in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

Now, currently UserA is logged in to Facebook through my application. when I call FB.api now then 'me' gets replaced to Facebook user_id of UserA(currently logged in user).

My issue :
Can I post message to UserB's profile when UserA is logged in to Facebook through my application. If yes, tell me how?

For this issue, In the above code I have tried by replacing UserB's Facebook user_id in place of 'me', but it doesn't work. However When I use FB.ui method for this issue, it works. Suggest me reasons.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I post message to UserB's profile when UserA is logged in to Facebook through my application. If yes, tell me how?

You can, by just using UserB’s user id or user name instead of `me`.

**But:** This feature will be removed soon (beginning of February 2013, see https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/), so it’s not worth developing something like that any more.

The only way to post to another user’s wall from then on will be to use the Feed dialog, and have the user (UserA) trigger the post himself actively.